# Scala type inference when mixing type member and type parameter

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have the following definitions:

```
trait Xode[+R] {
  type S = Option[R]
}
case class AXode(a: Int) extends Xode[Int]
case class BXode(b: String) extends Xode[String]

object xtore {
  private var m: Map[Xode[_], Xode[_]#S] = Map()

  def put[A <: Xode[_]](k: A)(v: A#S) {
    m += k -> v    
  }  
}
```

When executing the following, no error is raised, although I expect AXode#S to be Option[Int].

```
xtore.put(AXode(5))(Some("apples")) // <-- no error
```

What might happen is that `A` is inferred to be `Xode[_]`, and then `Xode[_]#S` gets to be `Option[_]`. Could I express my intention with type parameters?

When implemented with R being an abstract type member instead of a type parameter, it works as expected. Or dependent method types and typing `v: k.S` also helps. Is there any other construct?

Comment: `X[_]` means `X[Any]`. In particular your map does not relate the value types to the key types over the wild-carded argument to the `Xode` type constructor. In addition in `put`, scalac can widen the type of `A` to `Xode[Any]` if it needs to. Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure about what I'm writing ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm less concerned about the `Map` (its type can't express what I want, that's why I hide it), but would like `put` to behave correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Some (maybe slightly wrong explanation)

`X[_]` means `X[Any]`. In particular your map does not relate the value types to the key types over the wild-carded argument to the `Xode` type constructor. In addition in `put`, scalac can widen the type of `A` to `Xode[Any]` if it needs to. Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure about what I'm writing

#### Code that passes the question

The following rejects `xtore.put(AXode(5))(Some("apples"))` and accepts `xtore.put(AXode(5))(Some(0))`. Note that you also need to capture the type parameter of `Xode` as opposed to the `Xode[_]` version in the OP. I don't understand it completely and there might be a simpler solution.

```
  def put[A,B[X] <: Xode[X]](k: B[A])(v: B[A]#S) {
    m += k -> v    
  }
```